# Jquery get hit from tempary image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so what I am doing is creating an upload form for images that gets displayed as a thumbnail, sort of like a preview.  I have a set width that it is displayed and then in php on server side it is cropped to the size I want.  However, for client side preview I want to show it at the width I have specified but get the height of the image after being resized to the specified width and adjust it with javascript.  I hope that makes sense, anyway here is my code.  Im not very Jquery / javascript savy so I am probably missing something.

```
<script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var imgHeight = $(".previewlogo").height();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.previewlogo')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                $('.droparea')
                    .attr('style', 'height:', imgHeight, 'px;')
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
 }

        </script>
```

and then the html

```
<img class="previewlogo" src="#" alt="Click or Drag image here to add login logo"/>
<input type="file" class="droparea spot logoupload" name="logo" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

at the moment it is giving the size of the broken image size 39px; and also I am seeming to have an issue mixing the code with html on the .attr() tage, I am sure I am overlooking something

Answer (score 1):

I've fairly certain you won't be able to do anything with the image until after it is actually uploaded to the server.  This is because you'd be mixing local file content with remote content (a no-no in most browsers).  I suggest having your change handler submit the file immediately after they choose the image (perhaps using an ajax file upload method) and then show the resulting server image as your thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

In jquery there are better ways than using attr for style type changes.  For example css() related functions, like [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/).  Secondly, Jake is right about the security issue or as he put it (no-no).  Either way your JQuery should be improved as well, attr is for general access, not style.  You should also consider using a style application and not adding the attribute to it directly.